# What does a status bar icon that looks like a SIM card with a little house inside it mean?

Tags: samsung, 5.0-lollipop, notification-icons

I have Samsung Galaxy J1 Mini on Android 5.1.1 Lollipop. There is a status bar icon between the Wi-Fi and the signal icon that looks like a SIM card with a little house on it.

[image]

What does this icon?

Comment: Ah! Another case of companies putting icons on our screens without telling us what they mean.  And once again, it's Samsung doing it.  Bad Samsung, bad.